# How do I get the row count of a PivotTable that starts on a row other than the top one?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm using a PivotTable that will eventually have its values pasted to a separate workbook. The issue is that the filter tab is blocking the first row, the second row is blank and I don't need the headers from the third row. I also don't need the first 3 columns as they are not needed for the report.

The data I work with changes weekly so the number of rows will vary.

```
'Equitable is the name of the worksheet which was declared earlier in the code
    Dim BuysPivot As Worksheet
    Dim SummarySCS As Worksheet

    Set BuysPivot = Equitable.Sheets("Buys Pivot")
    Set SummarySCS = Equitable.Sheets("SCS_Summary")

    Dim PivotCt As Long

    PivotCt = BuysPivot.Cells(Rows.Count, "D4").End(xlDown).Row '---> Code fails
'1004 error. "Application-defined or object-defined error"
    BuysPivot.Range("D4:H" & PivotCt).Copy
    SummarySCS.Range("c2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

The code above should be able to Copy from D4 and down and paste it into the corresponding worksheet.

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Comment: Would the better solution be to interact with the PivotTable directly? I've not programmatically manipulated PivotTables before, but documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.databodyrange) suggests they have a `DataBodyRange` property (on which you could call `Rows.Count`)?

Comment: @chillin I'm still new to VBA so I was trying to stick with what I know. I'll fool around with this though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
PivotCt = BuysPivot.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlup).Row
```

You are trying to start at the very bottom cell and then go down. Instead you start at the bottom and work up to find the first non-empty cell.

And your syntax was a little off - `Cells` is row, column.